# Image overflow in visual lightbox

Tags: css

On [this page here](http://ryehome.com/photo.html)
The images look how I want in full screen. When I view in mobile or smaller screen sizes the images overflow the container.

[image overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQZgm.png)

How can I fix this in the css? 
edit: can't post link

Comment: do you want us to search the relevant piece of code inside this giant css stylesheet? plus, you must provide the relevant html code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the

```
 width: 450px from #vlightbox1 .vlightbox1
```

and add the next style to #vlightbox1 .vlightbox1 img

```
 width:100%
```

If you need something else don't hesitate to ask :)